# Entity Framework 6 Async e método .Wait()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um sistema que é um Web Api, o controle executa uma classes assim:

```
public class CrawlBO
{
    public void IniciaProcesso()
    {
        ...


        CarregaConfiguracaoCrawlBO carregaconfiguracaocrawlbo = new CarregaConfiguracaoCrawlBO(type);
        Task<ConfiguracaoCrawlModel> montarconfiguracao = carregaconfiguracaocrawlbo.MontarConfiguracaoAsync(type);

        ...

        montarconfiguracao.Wait();
        conf = montarconfiguracao.Result;

        ...
    }

}
```

Minha classe `CarregaConfiguracaoCrawlBO` tem um metodo `async`, essa é a classe:

```
public class CarregaConfiguracaoCrawlBO
{
    public async Task<ConfiguracaoCrawlModel> MontarConfiguracaoAsync(EnumOrigens type)
    {
        try
        {
            MYEntities db = new MYEntities ();
            int t = (int)type;

            CRAWL conf = await db.CRAWLs.Where(p => p.ID_ORIGEM == t).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            ...

            return c;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

O problema é que ele congela no `montarconfiguracao.Wait();`. Fiz todos os tipos de teste, e sei que dentro da `Task` ele congela na linha do `.FirstOrDefaultAsync();`.

Primeiro achei que poderia ser algum erro, aí coloquei o `try catch`, mas ele não pega erro, depois achei que poderia ser problema no `localhost`, mas no servidor ele trava no mesmo lugar também.

Gostaria de usar o `.Wait()` porque não tenho condições de colocar todos os métodos como `async` de uma vez só.

**Adicionando mais conteúdo:**

Eu sei que ele para no `.Wait()` para esperar a task, mas o problema que a task deveria demorar uns 4 segundos, e ele congela mesmo, uma hora depois e ainda ta lá na task sem fazer nada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás a experienciar um deadlock.

`Wait()` e `Result` podem levar a deadlocks, dependendo do execution context.

Imaginando que o método `MontarConfiguracaoAsync` foi implementado do seguinte modo:

```
public Task<ConfiguracaoCrawlModel> MontarConfiguracaoAsync()
{
    var result = await something();

    return result;
}
```

Este método vai executar `something` numa outra thread/IOCP e, quando `something` completar, o controlo vai voltar à thread principal para executar a instrução `return result`. O que acontece é que a thread principal ficou bloqueada no `MontarConfiguracaoAsync().Wait()`, e portanto a instrução `return result` não pode ser executada -> deadlock.

Para uma explicação mais detalhada, lê este excelente blog post do Stephen Cleary: [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

---

Para responder à pergunta do @ramaral:

> o primeiro código sei que não provoca deadlock, pois usa async no método e o segundo provoca ou não?

A solução usando `ContinueWith` não provocaria um deadlock. A única diferença entre usar `ContinueWith` e `await`, tanto quanto sei, está em exception handling. Com `await`, se alguma excepção for lançada durante a execução da task, a excepção será capturada e re-lançada (sem alterar a stack trace) na thread que iniciou a task.

Eis uma possivel sequencia de eventos:

1. Thread principal chama `MontarConfiguracaoAsync`
2. Thread principal cria uma instância de `MYEntities` e executa uma query na base de dados, iniciando uma IOCP (I/O Completion Port)
3. Thread principal volta ao método `IniciaProcesso` e cria uma "continuação" com `ContinueWith` que deverá ser executada na thread principal
4. A query termina, e a continuação é agendada para correr na thread principal assim que estiver livre
5. A thread principal continua a executar as restantes instruções de `IniciaProcesso` e termina, libertando a thread principal
6. A continuação é executa na thread principal

Answer (score 2):

Ao fazer `montarconfiguracao.Wait();` ele congela porque é isso que `Task.Wait()` faz: esperar que a *Task* finalize.

Para que tal não aconteça altere o código para:

```
public class CrawlBO
{

        public async Task IniciaProcesso()
        {

                ...

                CarregaConfiguracaoCrawlBO carregaconfiguracaocrawlbo = new CarregaConfiguracaoCrawlBO(type);
                Task<ConfiguracaoCrawlModel> montarconfiguracao = carregaconfiguracaocrawlbo.MontarConfiguracaoAsync(type);

                ...

                conf = await montarconfiguracao;
                //Após a linha anterior o método retorna

                //O código a partir daqui é executado após a Task finalizar
                // pode usar o valor de conf
                ...
        }

}
```

Se não quiser/puder utilizar `async` no método terá de fazer qualquer coisa do assim:

```
public class CrawlBO
{

    public void IniciaProcesso()
    {

        ...

        CarregaConfiguracaoCrawlBO carregaconfiguracaocrawlbo = new CarregaConfiguracaoCrawlBO(type);
        Task<ConfiguracaoCrawlModel> montarconfiguracao = carregaconfiguracaocrawlbo.MontarConfiguracaoAsync(type);

        ...

        montarconfiguracao.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                //O código aqui é executado após a Task finalizar
                conf = t.Result;
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

         //O código aqui é executado antes da task finalizar
         ...
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu acho que eu não escrevi bem, o problema é que ela congela mesmo! Se executar o `.FirstOrDefault` sem o `async` ele executa em 3 segundos, mas com o `async` ele congela para mais de hora e eu nunca vi ele sair do `Wait()`. Melhorei a pergunta.

Comment: Você no método `MontarConfiguracaoAsync()` está a retornar a varável `c` foi erro ao postar o código ou está mesmo assim? O método deveria retornar `conf`.

Comment: @user3517631 Isso e' um deadlock, ve a minha resposta para mais detalhes.

Comment: @dcastro Tire-me uma dúvida: o primeiro código sei que não provoca *deadlock*, pois usa *async* no método e o segundo provoca ou não?

Comment: @ramaral Boa pergunta - editei a minha resposta para responder a essa pergunta também (nao coube num comentário)